# Binary search an ordered List<int>

Tags: c#, generics

Given a `List<int> myValues` which I know to be ordered, what is the quickest way to determine if `X` is in the given list?

Do I really have to write my own binary search?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can use `list.Contains(value)`, but if you really need binary search list already has it implemented: `list.BinarySearch()`.

Comment: Ah if only I'd tried the most obvious thing first. BinarySearch method  is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to search through a list is [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx):

```
if (myValues.Contains(x)) {
```

Though this only performs a linear search, which means that the execution time is depending on the size of the list and if the item is found at the beginning of the list or at the end.

A true binary search can be done with [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx). For a binary search to work the element *should* implement it's own comparison method (implementing `IComparable<T>`), or you provide the search with a comparer.

```
if (myValues.BinarySarch(x)) {
```

Comment: List<>.Contains() is a linear search so will be much slower than a binary search for larger lists (O(n) rather than O(log n).

Answer (score 1):

There's a binary search function provided:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>() {314,1592,6535};
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", myList.BinarySearch(6535), myList[myList.BinarySearch(6535)]);
```